# How do I execute a command on already opened browser from a ruby file

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I use cucumber framework for testing web application, as i develop my scripts i have to launch the browser again and again every time after adding something to my code. My question is "Is it possible to execute a command on already opened browser from a ruby(.rb ) file" ??. Which will save me a lot of time . My framework is based on cucumber, capybara and selenium  webdriver.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's not possible to use existing browser with Selenium Webdriver.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18)

However, there drivers (Capybara-Webkit, Poltergeist, Webdriver's HtmlUnitDriver) that are faster and have less startup time than browsers. Maybe, they will be good for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I achieve it without using webdriver, i mean only using ruby????

Comment: @Kalyan I don't think so. Managing browser is a complex task. I don't  any library for it except Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want exactly... if you have to "F5" everytime you change something in the UI-Code, you may consider using the guard gem.

guard + guard-livereload and the rack-livereload included in your app automatically updates the browser if you edit "views".

Comment: He wants to attach driver to already running browser (he doesn't want to start browser every time when he runs test)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a monkey-patched version of Selenium Webdriver, which keeps PhantomJS browser open between test runs. See this blog post: http://blog.sharetribe.com/2014/04/07/faster-cucumber-startup-keep-phantomjs-browser-open-between-tests/

The trick is to stub the `Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS::Service.create_process` method and tell the Selenium Driver to use the default port 8910 even though it is reserved.

You can add this piece of code to your config/test.rb file:

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::PortProber
  def self.free?(port)
    true
  end
end

class Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS::Service
  def create_process(args)
    puts "Starting monkey-patched PhantomJS Selenium Webdriver"

    Struct.new("ChildProcessFake") do
      def start() end
      def exited?() true end
    end.new
  end
end
```

Now you can start PhantomJS in a terminal tab:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=8910
```

And when you have PhantomJS running, you can start your Cucumber tests.

Obviously this works only for PhantomJS, but something similar could work with other browsers too.