# Can Selenium webdriver attach to already open browser window?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

After a lot of searching I believe this feature is not implemented yet- but does anyone know of any workaround implemented for Java with selenium1/2 that i can try? If a different process started the instance of the browser , can webdriver connect to that window? Any workarounds that can be tried. Any pointers is much appreciated.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 5):

Nope, it can't be done.  It's one of the [oldest feature requests](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18) for WebDriver, and it isn't going to happen any time soon.  Sorry!

Comment: I did see somewhere hack how to do it, but I am unable to find it. Anyway, your answer is correct ;)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. If anyone finds any workarounds in future please post it here. Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session

Comment: @ClementHoang Yup.  And the [Selenium project leader closed it](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18#c48) on 2014-01-29 as "not feasible".

Comment: Booo!  This would be so very useful.