# How can I use ChromeDriver on a previously opened web page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `selenium` for automation and I'm using `Chromedriver`.

Is there a way to control or fill in a web page that is previously opened - not opened with `Navigate().GoToUrl()`?  For example:

1. Start Chrome
2. Open a web page
3. Start ChromeDriver
4. Point ChromeDriver to the previously opened web page
5. Fill in text in a text box on that web page

Comment: Did you try driver.navigate().back();       ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. Only a browser instance opened as a WebDriver instance can be controlled by WebDriver. Why would you need to do the above? There may be a work around people could suggest if a little more context is provided. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Selenium webdriver attach to already open browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960692/can-selenium-webdriver-attach-to-already-open-browser-window)

Comment: Mark, thanks for your comment.  What I am trying to do is fill in a web page from a C# program.  The C# program has a list of "answers" that I want to use to fill in text boxes in the web page.  Simply, click on a table entry in my C# program then click on the text box in the web page; the text in the chosen table entry is filled in the clicked web page text box.