# How to run selenium python script in current window session?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

When I'm writing a selenium python script, I have to start a session with some command like

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

However, this opens a new browser window.

What I would like is to have the window that is already open be accessed by the script, much like it would be if I have started the selenium IDE add-on (that cannot run python scripts afaik).

Could anybody please tell me if there is a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often wanted this functionality with Selenium and Python myself.  Unfortunately, it's not part of Selenium's current features.

For more info, check out the answer threads here:

[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

(looks like someone came up with a hack solution, but I haven't tested it)

and here:

[Can Selenium webdriver attach to already open browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960692/can-selenium-webdriver-attach-to-already-open-browser-window)

Good luck!