# How to use/attach an existing browser using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

What is the Selenium equivalent to attaching an existing browser in Watir?

```
brw = Watir::IE.attach(:title, "Google")
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 8):

This is a duplicate answer 
**Reconnect to a driver in python selenium **
This is applicable on all drivers.
1. open a driver

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

2. extract to session_id and _url from driver object.

```
url = driver.command_executor._url       #"http://127.0.0.1:60622/hub"
session_id = driver.session_id            #'4e167f26-dc1d-4f51-a207-f761eaf73c31'
```

3. Use these two parameter to connect to your driver.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url,desired_capabilities={})
driver.session_id = session_id
```

And you are connected to your driver again.

```
driver.get("http://www.mrsmart.in")
```

Comment: Good, but one problem is, the second test process will start a new browser. Could that be avoid?

Comment: Do not initiate a new webdriver but for testing purpose it is good practice to initiate a new browser for each test case.

Comment: If I'm not wrong , actually the new browser (with new session created ) started is useless.  we will use the existing old session to conduct the task.

Comment: Got error "urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>" When I try to reconnect chromedriver, Is there a way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: driver.session_id is not valid syntax! (session_id cannot be resolved or is not a field)

Comment: are you using python api for selenium web driver.

Comment: This is not the existing browser we meant,  we mean a browser opened by double click the desktop CHROME ICON!

Comment: @Jcyrss im not sure if it is possible to avoid opening a second browser, but what u can do is before setting the old session id, close the newly opened browser with driver.close()

Answer (score 5):

1. Run a Webdriver first

   > driver = new FirefoxDriver();
2. Now run a RemoteWebdriver

   > DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   >    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7055/hub"),capabilities);

The RemoteWebdriver will attach to the first browser window running Webdriver and it will not create a new window.

---

Note: Run Webdriver (1) and RemoteWebdriver (2) in separate programs one-by-one).

Comment: Correct! Here's how to attach to a running server using `selenium-webdriverjs`: `var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
   .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
   .usingServer('http://localhost:9515')
   .build();
`. Run this after you've launched .e.g. `chromedriver --port=9515`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, I was not aware that we could do this on Chrome as well..!! Do you mind explaining me how to launch a chromedriver on port=9515? As Firefox default port is 7055 it works fine for me but how about Chrome?

Comment: Just run `chromedriver --port=9515` after [downloading ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)... if I understand the question correctly?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I'm just wondering what code/syntax you use to launch it on 9515 port? 

driver = new ChromeDriver(); --> will this do?

Comment: @DanDascalescu I managed to run chromedriver --port=9515 and after that every time when I run the above webdriver code it opens a new chrome browser and it is not attaching to the first one!