# Attaching Chrome and Firefox Browser

Tags: ruby, watir

I ususally attach the IE window with the below code like

```
b=Watir::IE.attach(:index,0)
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to attach the Chrome and Firefox browser like I shown above

Comment: Unfortunately it is not currently possible - see [How to use/attach an existing browser using Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386418/how-to-use-attach-an-existing-browser-using-selenium)

Comment: HI Justin Ko, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use plugins for this.

Please have a look at:
[The chrome driver](https://rubygems.org/gems/chromedriver-helper/versions/0.0.8)
& [Firefox driver](https://rubygems.org/gems/firewatir)

Comment: hi, I am using watir-webdriver 0.7.0, Do I still need to install the above two package? If I install that, Can I attach the chrome browser?