# How can I check whether new page is completely loaded or not using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

Is there any way I can check whether a particular page completely loaded or not using Watir?

I tried with `browser.status` but it's not printing anything.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by completely loaded?

Comment: Looking at [watir-spec](https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/browser_spec.rb), `#status` is browser-dependent.  But--FWIW--that method doesn't seem to work for me on any browser (and I can't recall ever using it).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you mean by completely loaded? All HTML or all HTML and JavaScripts.

For HTML

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
#To check if page has been loaded
ready = browser.ready_state.eql? "complete"
#To wait until page has been loaded
browser.wait
```

For JavaScript and HTML. For these you have to wait for each specific element
This code will wait until the element i enable, meaning clickable.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new    
browser.text_field(:id => 'id_of_object').wait_until_present
```

Comment: hi, First of all, I was asking the watir code, not selenium code and then Even I know this waiting code something like b.text_field.when_present.set() or I could use wait_until_present, but I don't want this, When I check the browser, if the page is being loaded, then it needs to tell me false, it's loaded completely then it needs to be tell me true.

Comment: Ad stated you can only check if the HTML has been loaded. If you have javascripts loading afterwards it will not wait for them. Then you have to wait for the specific element

Comment: hi, I have executed your code but it throws the following error for me.
"`<main>': undefined method `ready_state' for #<Watir::Browser:0x..fc4dc3de4 url="about:blank" title=""> (NoMethodError)

Comment: What are your gems version number?

Comment: watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (3.7.0)
watir-webdriver (0.7.0)

Comment: hi I tried with 'watir (5.0.0 x86-mingw32, 4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (4.0.1, 3.7.0)
watir-webdriver (0.7.0)' as well, but throws the same error "`<main>': undefined method `ready_state' for #<Watir::Browser:0x7552f376 url="about:blank" title=""> (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Can you check this? lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb for ready_state

Comment: hi, Thank you very much, Actually I was using WATIR instead of WATI-WEBDRIVER, that's what I haven't gotten the output, As soon as I use the WATIR-WEBDRIVER, it's reported correctly. But is it not possible in WATIR?

Comment: Watir almost doesnt have any functions at all. See [Watir Doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir)

Comment: Okay, I am scared to use this watir-webdriver because it doesn't provide the way to attach the browser like Watir::IE.attach(:index,0).

Comment: See link for ways to do it in watir-webdriver. [link](http://h3manth.com/content/watir-webdriver-attach-window)

Comment: Also see this [link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386418/how-to-use-attach-an-existing-browser-using-selenium)

Comment: hi, I know of this link before 'http://h3manth.com/content/watir-webdriver-attach-window', But it's not working for me, did you try that out by yourself? If I opened more than browser, I can't connect to the previous browsers as he explained in his article, Could you please try that out and let me know whether it's working for you?