# How to use a running instance of Firefox with Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, python-3.4

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 49.0.2, Python 3.4.3 & Selenium 3.0.1

I want to use Selenium to automate some browser functions, not to do any web site testing. How can I can I modify the simple login script below to use the instance of Firefox running on my desktop instead of opening a new Firefox window?

```
# login_yahoo_mail.py

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=us')
enter_email = driver.find_element_by_id('login-username')
enter_email.clear()
enter_email.send_keys('cleanman2@yahoo.com')
next_button = driver.find_element_by_id('login-signin')
next_button.click()
enter_password = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-passwd')))
enter_password.send_keys('dumba$$yahoo!^!&')
signin_button = driver.find_element_by_id('login-signin')
signin_button.click()
```

Thanks,  Jim

Comment: If the purposes aren't for testing, there are easier ways to automate browser functions on an already open instance using javascript directly, for example Greasemonkey.

Comment: I haven't used javascript or Greasemonkey for a long time and don't want to relearm them right now. I would prefer using Python if possible.

Comment: Before anyone tells me, I just changed my password.  I had to repaste the code and forgot to munge the log on info the second time. Dumb mistake, my apologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use/attach an existing browser using Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386418/how-to-use-attach-an-existing-browser-using-selenium)

Comment: I looked at them before asking this question and they did not help me. They talk of remote servers, session id's and java patches. I am trying to determine if I can use Firefox running on my desktop. If I open a Firefox window I don't think there is a session id to attach to at that point, maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with 'Selenium 4'.

Each window has a unique identifier which remains persistent in a single session. You can get the window handle of the current window by using:
`driver.current_window_handle`

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Store the ID of the original window
original_window = driver.current_window_handle

# Opens a new tab and switches to new tab
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')

# Opens a new window and switches to new window
driver.switch_to.new_window('window')

#Close the tab or window
driver.close()

#Switch back to the old tab or window
driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
```

I haven't try it yet but since Webdriver doesn't know where the OS focus is, you can find the way you want with those options.

More: [Windows and tabs handle](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#windows-and-tabs)