# How can I move WebDriver to new opened Chrome tab without knowing index?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I am using the Selenium Python Bindings for web browser automation in Chrome. As part of the automation script, I click on a link and the website opens the page in a new tab. However, the WebDriver object in my python script is still pointing to the first tab.

I have tried all of the options offered on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28716311/3131147) but none were successful.

The only code I have been able to get to work so far is this:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

The problem I have with this is that I'm afraid I can't guarantee that the new tab will be at index 1, nor do I think I can guarantee that the new tab is at the last index. I did try using keys like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

But using some logging I saw that the driver was still pointing to the first tab. Is there a way to focus on the current tab that chrome is showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I have cases like these I switch to the last window handle, so far it worked for me:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: I had no idea -1 would automatically switch to the last tab, thanks for that! I will try it out, but unfortunately the website I'm automating is down for maintenance (just my luck) but I will let you know how it works.