# Python and selenium, is not possible to open a new tab with a URL?

Tags: python, selenium

I've been digging around this but no luck. So my question is: is not possible to open a new url in a new tab ? ( in this case using IE).
My scenario is, open IE, open website, log into it, do some tasks, then open a new tab with a new url in that tab. When I do that, the new url always open in the first tab, not in the new one. I looked for some solutions online but any worked and found many people with same issue. Code follows below:

```
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

        path_to_Ie = 'C:\\Python34\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe' # change path as needed
        browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path = path_to_Ie)
        url = 'www.test1.com'
        browser.get(url)


        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']").send_keys("user")
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']").send_keys("pass")

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-link']").click()

    # some coding here


        browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') #open new tab

        browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB) # it looks like it switches to the correct tab, but anyway the browser.get will open the url in the first tab

        browser.get('www.test2.com') # this link must open in this new tab -> but it doesnt.


        import os
        os.system("taskkill /im IEDriverServer.exe")
```

thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Arman thank you for your comments. already saw before that post. I open the new tab correctly, the issue is that the new URL doesnt open in that tab. Open in the first one,-

Comment: @Gonzalo Look at Arman's answer, you are not doing it like in that answer.

Comment: @Fredrik I believe it doesnt work also, I've tried also and gives an error:     selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN)
AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'

Comment: I guess you should not just open new tab but switch to it also

Comment: look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium

Comment: @Andersson It makes sense, though I tried also that but didnt work.. i've read many other questions concerning this but any attempt of solution worked for me.. :/

Comment: Quick update, it seems that the the tab switch using for example "browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)" to the second tab, but anyway when i do browser get it comes back to first tab, is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.execute_script("window.open('www.test2.com','_blank');")
```

This works for `Chrome`, but in `IE` it will open new window instead of new tab. If it doesn't matter for you then you can try it

Comment: actually it matters, must be the same window in IE, and new tab. thank you for yr comment