# Python Selenium with Chrome. How to switch between different tabs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I click a button which opens a new tab. How to I then navigate around the new tab?

This sounds like a simple task but after several hours trying to find a solution I'm not any closer. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Tried using keys for CONTROL + 'T' and read other suggestions but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28716311/3642398

Answer (score 5):

I just implemented my solution and it worked for my case, which looks very similar to yours.

First you need to check the `window_handles`:

```
len(driver.window_handles) > 1
```

If you have more than one, you can try to switch to your second handler:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: Did not work on Chrome with the latest selenium and chrome driver

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya, does `driver.window_handles` a length greater than one? Have you tried to inspect its content?

Comment: Yes It had a length greater than 1, I printed it out onto the console. I gave up on chrome tabs, using firefox now.

Comment: Hum, weird, I was able to use it on Chrome some time ago. Anyway, [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) is the piece of documentation I used.

Comment: Akshay, you have to wait for the second tab to show in the list. You have to use sleep for better results