# switch between tabs and perform action on individual using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to extract URLs, open them into a new tab and then perform some actions. My code is-

```
urls = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="maincontent"]/table/tbody/tr/td//a[@href]')
        for url in urls:

            try:
                href = url.get_attribute("href")[28:]
                print href
                actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
                url_1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="'+href+'"]')
                actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(url_1).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
            except Exception, e:
                print e

        actions1 = ActionChains(self.driver)      
        actions1.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
        print "hi"
        show_report = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@value="Show Report(s)"]')
        show_report.click()
```

It opens the URLs in new tabs but is not performing action on them. What should I do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change focus to the new tab as they usually get opened in the background. Then you'll need to grab a handle for the now current tab.

This is described [here](https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903):

> ```
> import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
> import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> from time import sleep    
>
> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
> browser.get('https://www.google.com?q=python#q=python')
> first_result = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_class_name('rc'))
> first_link = first_result.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
>
> # Save the window opener (current window, do not mistaken with tab... not the same)
> main_window = browser.current_window_handle
>
> # Open the link in a new tab by sending key strokes on the element
> # Use: Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN to open tab on top of the stack 
> first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
>
> # Switch tab to the new tab, which we will assume is the next one on the right
> browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
>
> # Put focus on current window which will, in fact, put focus on the current visible tab
> browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
>
> # do whatever you have to do on this page, we will just got to sleep for now
> sleep(2)
>
> # Close current tab
> browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
>
> # Put focus on current window which will be the window opener
> browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
> ```

Comment: Keys like send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w') , send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') are not working

Comment: @V.Khakhil You'll need to use whatever keys are appropriate for your browser and OS. `ctrl+w` and `ctrl+t` should work across the three main browsers in Windows.

Comment: i am using window 7 and chrome web driver but still these keys not working

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28716311/367865) lists some other ways to switch tabs.