# Get URLs of all open tabs using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating a webdriver instance using selenium for some automation work. I am opening multiple tabs at a time and would like to know if there is a way to get the URLs of all the tabs open.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.current_url
```

The above code provides me with the URL of the first tab only. Another thing I tried was:

```
driver.window_handles[0].current_url
```

The above solution failed as `window_handles()` returns a unicode object which does not contain `current_url` I prefer not going through all the tabs actively in order to find the `current_url` of each tab as it would disrupt the automation task at hand.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458138/switch-between-tabs-and-perform-action-on-individual-using-selnium#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to loop through each window handle, switch to it and print the url

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: I get the idea behind this, but in this case the script should scroll through all the tabs in order to find the URLs. This is something I want to avoid

Comment: You can't avoid that. you need to switch to window to get details of it, and only one window can be used at a time

Comment: Makes sense that selenium is unaware of the state of content in each tab until it arrives there. I imagine this is where selenium differs to the browser's engine to get more work done without communicating...