# Need to switch between tabs in python

Tags: python

I am using Beautifulsoup using python. I need to switch between tabs of some application. can you please help me on how to switch between tabs in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "switch between tabs"?

Comment: Suppose I am in login tab and need to switch onto the next tab Fufillment tab. How do i do this in python script. Thanks a lot for an immediate reply

Comment: Missing code (no homeworks here, just help to your own efforts) and malformed question

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use selenium (or some other) to access the code and switch the tabs, and BeautifulSoup to process the code, that is what works for me best. To use selenium you will need an executable, chromedriver for example.

Check out the accepted answer of this link for an example: [How do I switch to the active tab in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium)