# Selenium doesn't seem to work on this website. Why is that? What can I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate a procedure with selenium on the website Plus500, but I can't even get to log in. I just get the TimeoutException without being able to locate the part of the page where I need to enter my credentials.
This is the code that I'm using for the log in but I fear the problem is a more general one. Does anyone know why is this happening?

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://app.plus500.com/trade?refurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&innerTags=_cc_%20exp_new_sas_c&webvisitid=2a3139bc-78f7-4f48-a50d-c79e7b3e7abd&page=login&_ga=2.24870842.1255829517.1590833562-259196075.1590833562', 'new window')")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="email"]'))).send_keys('myemail')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys('mypassword') 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submitLogin"]'))).click()
```

Comment: P.s. The first line is just to open the page in a different tab

Comment: Did you try more than 10 in delay wait?

Comment: Yes, I tried up to 50. By the way the error is related to the first WebDriverWait command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell selenium which tab it should consider active, opening a new tab does not change the active tab in selenium's perspective. There are multiple options to achieve this, like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28716311/8375783).

Basically you need to add this extra line after opening a new tab: `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])` and selenium will know that you want it to execute commands on the last tab in the browser.

So the fixed code is:

```py
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://app.plus500.com/trade?refurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&innerTags=_cc_%20exp_new_sas_c&webvisitid=2a3139bc-78f7-4f48-a50d-c79e7b3e7abd&page=login&_ga=2.24870842.1255829517.1590833562-259196075.1590833562', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="email"]'))).send_keys('myemail')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys('mypassword') 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submitLogin"]'))).click()
```