# Switching focus to new tab python selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I have a python selenium code to test a website. Now once the driver click on a link in the 1st tab, it opens it up in a new tab, but the focus stays on the previous tab, and I am not able to reference any elements in the new tab.

How can change the focus to the new?

Also both the tabs are open in the same browser and I am using Chrome browser

Comment: this should get you going: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28716311/6770704

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch to the active tab in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

name each window if you are working with a few number of windows. using this chunk you can name and switch between tabs

```
window1= driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the window handles, record the counts of window handles and switch with count - 1. Check below.

```
n = 0
for handle in driver.window_handles:
       n+=1
driver.switch_to_window(n-1)
```

If you encounter any difficulty, please paste your code for further elucidation.