# Python - How do I switch between tabs in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browser, tabs, webbrowser-control

I'm new to python and selenium and I'm trying to switch between tabs, I've already tried using the normal key commands, ActionChains, and Keys.CONTROL, but it's not working, how would I do this. The program is the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import webbrowser
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import multiprocessing


driver1  = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\mydriver\chromedriver")
  
ar = ['https://google.com', 'https://bing.com']
for page1 in (ar):
    driver1.execute_script(f"window.open ('{page1}')")
    time.sleep(3)

for x in range (5):
    driver1.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

Comment: I see one problem at this line `for page1 in (ar):` it should be `for page1 in ar:`

Comment: You can use Selenium's `window_handles` - try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium:

Comment: ah got it   driver1.switch_to.window(driver1.window_handles[-1]), which goes back 1, i was trying to [1], thank you

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this guide:
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-switch-tabs-in-selenium-python

But this is the key part:

```
#get current window handle
p = driver.current_window_handle

#get first child window
chwd = driver.window_handles

for w in chwd:
#switch focus to child window
    if(w!=p):
    driver.switch_to.window(w)
break
time.sleep(0.9)
print("Child window title: " + driver.title)
```