# How to webscrape a popup on a new page with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to know how to webscrape a popup on a new page with selenium (or another framework).
The Python code below clicks on a button then a new page opens but I don't know to copy/paste the promo code. Can you help ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome




class Coupons_offers:



def stayOpen(self):
    opts = ChromeOptions()
    opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = Chrome(chrome_options=opts)

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.get("https://www.offers.com/scotch-porter/")
    sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="_evidon-banner-acceptbutton"]').click()
    sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/div[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
    sleep(4)
    self.driver.get("https://www.offers.com/scotch-porter/#offer_id=4467763")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/div[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]').click()` a new tab is opened.
Now you have to switch driver to the new tab with `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`
When on the new tab you can get the text from element located by `//div[@class='coupon-code']` `xpath`
Now you can close the new opened tab by `driver.close`
And switch back to the previous tab by `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])`
See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

The modal window is loaded from external URL. You can use this code how to parse the coupon code (just replace the offerid for ID what you want):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.offers.com/exit/modal/offerid/4467763/"  # <-- replace offerid here

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find(class_="coupon-code").text)
```

Prints:

```
SIGNUP15
```

Comment: Very nice way, I have to learn it ;)
But he asked about Selenium approach

Comment: @Prophet Well, he can load this URL with selenium....but.... ;)

Comment: Again, I see how nice this way. I indeed want to learn this in the nearest future. But the way he is doing (and possible even doesn't know about this approach) is a legacy Selenium.

Comment: Thank you for your help. it is easier  with BS :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will probably need to get the window handle of the new window and go to it. To debug, try

```
Whandles = driver.window_handles
print(Whandles)
```

And it should be clear what the window handle is for your new window. Then you can do

```
driver.switch_to_window_(desiredWindowHandle)
```

before proceeding with code to use the new window.