# How to send keys with python selenium after an element has loaded?

Tags: python, selenium

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as when
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time; from datetime import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/wit/PycharmProjects/gmeet-automation/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://classroom.google.com")
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gfe-main-content"]/section[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a')
element.click()

wait = webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
usernameField = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId')
username = wait.until(when.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, usernameField)))
#username = webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(when.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId'))))
time.sleep(1)
username.send_keys("xxx)
```

Here I made an attempt of using the `WebDriverWait` function to allow time for the text box to be loaded before sending the keys.

But it errored and returned this:

```
File "/home/wit/PycharmProjects/gmeet-automation/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId')
  File "/home/wit/PycharmProjects/gmeet-automation/venv/git/google-meet-project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/home/wit/PycharmProjects/gmeet-automation/venv/git/google-meet-project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/wit/PycharmProjects/gmeet-automation/venv/git/google-meet-project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="identifierId"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
```

The selector ID is correct, being `identifierId`, but since it isn't loaded properly the code could not find and input text. How should I correct the function used for waiting the element to load in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing selector with web element.
Here

```py
usernameField = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId')
```

`usernameField` is web element.  While here

```py
username = wait.until(when.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, usernameField)))
```

`usernameField` should be a string.
Also I'd suggest to prefer using `visibility_of_element_located` when possible instead of `element_to_be_clickable`
So, to make your code working try change it as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time; from datetime import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/wit/PycharmProjects/gmeet-automation/chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://classroom.google.com")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gfe-main-content"]/section[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a'))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "identifierId"))).send_keys("xxx)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of a better EC function!
But it turned out I needed to switch focus since a new tab opened in order to be able to find the element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium