# How to use Selenium WebDriver with two tabs with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to run the code. However, at some point when I click the button, the form opens in a new tab and the code fails to continue. How do I make selenium recognize that it should continue in the new tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch to the active tab in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `window_handles` and `switch_to.window` method:

```
last_tab = driver.window_handles[-1]
driver.switch_to.window(last_tab)
```

Then to switch back to the first tab use

```
driver.switch_to.window( driver.window_handles[0] )
```

Comment: How can i do this?