# Connect to an already opened browser

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

For a user already using Firefox (or any other) is there a way to connect to that browser using selenium?

Conditions:

- the browser icon was **clicked on** by the user.
- i do not want a new window to pop up (when using selenium).

Example: a user wishes to log into Facebook and wants a program to enter his lengthy password (i can do this with the webdriver etc...).

Is there a way to connect (to an already opened browser) and send commands to that browser?

Comment: this is similar to gadgets that handle and enter passwords.

Comment: Yes, but you should use Selenium IDE(FireFox add-on) instead of WebDriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use switch function. You can switch to new browser by `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])` then you can drive it. If you want to switch back to first window `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])`.

```
>>> driver.window_handles
[u'{7355ca99-910b-554d-8478-f8a550e0c767}']
>>> driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
>>> driver.window_handles
[u'{7355ca99-910b-554d-8478-f8a550e0c767}', u'{5a0824a9-9d55-0841-87b8-35a26d4a8b83}']
>>> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#email").send_keys("dfjd@ak.com")
>>> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
>>> # write your case to parent window
```