# WebDriver Java: Reattach existing webdriver browser session to a driver instance

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I'm looking for a way to reattach an existing webdriver browser session to a driver instance so i could control the browser again.

So far, I've tried the following:
**I.** ==========================================

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38827934/2285470

**Browser:** Firefox v. 51.01 / Chrome v. 56.0.2924.87

**Driver:** geckodriver v. 0.14 / chromedriver v. 2.27

**Solution tried:**
1. Create a custom class that extends RemoteWebDriver

```
public class RemoteDriver extends RemoteWebDriver {
    public RemoteDriver(URL url, String sessionId) {
        super();
        setSessionId(sessionId);
        setCommandExecutor(new HttpCommandExecutor(url) {
            @Override
            public Response execute(Command command) throws IOException {
                if (command.getName() != "newSession") {
                    return super.execute(command);
                }
                return super.execute(new Command(getSessionId(), "getCapabilities"));
            }
        });
        startSession(new DesiredCapabilities());
    }
}
```

2. Start a new firefox instance
3. Get the session Id and store it somewhere (property file)
4. Stop the test, leave the browser open
5. Invoke the custom class that extends the RemoteWebDriver using the following:

   `RemoteDriver cdriver = new RemoteDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7055/hub"),"my-session-id");`

**Result:** `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No command or response codec has been defined. Unable to proceed` on the line `return super.execute(new Command(getSessionId(), "getCapabilities"));`

**II.** ==========================================
**Reference:** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/1LygDvlQ3H4

**Browser:** Firefox v. 51.01 / Chrome v. 56.0.2924.87

**Driver:** geckodriver v. 0.14 / chromedriver v. 2.27

**Solution tried:**
1. Create a custom class that extends RemoteWebDriver

```
public class RemoteDriver extends RemoteWebDriver {
    @Override
    protected void startSession(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
        String sid = getSessionIdFromPropertyFile();
        if (sid != null) {
            setSessionId(sid);
            try {
                super.startSession(desiredCapabilities);
            } catch (WebDriverException e) {
                // session is not valid
                sid = null;
            }
        }
        if (sid == null) {
            super.startSession(desiredCapabilities);
            saveSessionIdToPropertyFile(getSessionId().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

2. Start a new firefox instance
3. Get the session Id and store it somewhere (property file)
4. Stop the test, leave the browser open
5. Invoke the custom class that extends the RemoteWebDriver using the following:

   `RemoteDriver cdriver = new RemoteDriver();`
   `cdriver.startSession(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());`
   `cdriver.get("https://www.google.com");`

**Result:** `org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.`

Seems others can get it to work but after a few hours of trying I still unable to do this.

I'm using selenium-java version 3.1.0

Thanks in advance.