# Selenium WebDriver C# Attached with already open Chrome Browser

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using WebDriver C# for Chrome Automation. I want to attach driver to already opened Chrome Instance.

I am struggling since long time; I hope here I got correct and proper answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Comment: Before asking a question, you should spend some time googling your question and do some research.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, attaching to an existing browser is not possible, and there are not plans to implement that functionality: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18.