# Get URL of current tab firefox python

Tags: python, selenium

This is my first contact with selenium and I'm trying to get URL of the current tab opened in firefox. My OS - Ubuntu 16.04.
That's what I have :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.system('wmctrl -a firefox')
print webdriver.Firefox.current_url
```

That's what I've got:

```
<property object at 0x7fc5041a4a48>
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the driver. like this `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` then you can get the current url with `browser.current_url`

Comment: See the example in the docs on how to set up the browser correctly: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: I also tried to create an instance of driver, but it creates me a new Firefox window and print a result for this new window

Comment: Doesn't look like its possible with just an existing window. In general you want to create a web driver and then connect it to the site you want. According to some answers here though there's a hack if you already created a web driver that you can connect another to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session

Comment: @Cfreak Get it, that's what I was looking for