# How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, session, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

For some unknown reasons ,my browser open test pages of my remote server very slowly. So I am thinking if I can reconnect to the browser after quitting the script but don't execute `webdriver.quit()` this will leave the browser opened. It is probably kind of HOOK or webdriver handle.
I have looked up the selenium API doc but didn't find any function.
I'm using Chrome 62,x64,windows 7,selenium 3.8.0.
I'll be very appreciated whether the question can be solved or not.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Have you tried reusing the chrome existing user directory by using the option 'user-data-dir' instead of webdriver creating a new one each time. Instead of downloading chrome will use stuff from the cache.

Comment: @Grasshopper What is this black magic? I used this Chromeoption.And it reduced plenty of loading time. I'll lookup for this .Thank you very much.

Comment: It is the cache helping load the page so fast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**, you can't reconnect to the previous *Web Browsing Session* after you quit the script. Even if you are able to extract the `Session ID`, `Cookies` and other session attributes from the previous *Browsing Context* still you won't be able to pass those attributes as a *HOOK* to the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871).

A cleaner way would be to call `webdriver.quit()` and then span a new *Browsing Context*.

---

### Deep Dive

There had been a lot of discussions and attempts around to reconnect *WebDriver* to an existing running *Browsing Context*. In the discussion [Allow webdriver to attach to a running browser](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18) ***Simon Stewart*** [Creator WebDriver] clearly mentioned:

> - Reconnecting to an existing *Browsing Context* is a browser specific feature, hence can't be implemented in a generic way.
> - With [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), it's possible to iterate over the open windows in the OS and find the right IE process to attach to.
> - [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) needs to be started in a specific mode and configuration, which effectively means that just
>     attaching to a running instance isn't technically possible.

---

### tl; dr

[webdriver.firefox.useExisting not implemented](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2163)

Comment: You totally understand and solved my confusion. I'll do cleanup . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

### **Yes**, that's actually quite easy to do.

A selenium <-> webdriver session is represented by a connection url and session_id, you just reconnect to an existing one.

**Disclaimer** - the approach is using selenium internal properties ("private", in a way), which may change in new releases; you'd better not use it for production code; it's better not to be used against remote SE (yours hub, or provider like BrowserStack/Sauce Labs), because of a caveat/resource drainage explained at the end.

When a webdriver instance is initiated, you need to get the before-mentioned properties; sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

# now Google is opened, the browser is fully functional; print the two properties
# command_executor._url (it's "private", not for a direct usage), and session_id

print(f'driver.command_executor._url: {driver.command_executor._url}')
print(f'driver.session_id: {driver.session_id}')
```

With those two properties now known, another instance can connect; the "trick" is to initiate a `Remote` driver, and provide the `_url` above - thus it will connect to that running selenium process:

```
driver2 = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=the_known_url)  
# when the started selenium is a local one, the url is in the form 'http://127.0.0.1:62526'
```

When that is ran, you'll see a new browser window being opened.
That's because upon initiating the driver, the selenium library automatically starts a new session for it - and now you have 1 webdriver process with 2 sessions (browsers instances).

If you navigate to an url, you'll see it is executed on that new browser instance, not the one that's left from the previous start - which is not the desired behavior.
At this point, two things need to be done - a) close the current SE session ("the new one"), and b) switch this instance to the previous session:

```
if driver2.session_id != the_known_session_id:   # this is pretty much guaranteed to be the case
    driver2.close()   # this closes the session's window - it is currently the only one, thus the session itself will be auto-killed, yet:
    driver2.quit()    # for remote connections (like ours), this deletes the session, but does not stop the SE server

# take the session that's already running
driver2.session_id = the_known_session_id

# do something with the now hijacked session:
driver.get('https://www.bing.com/')
```

And, that is it - you're now connected to the previous/already existing session, with all its properties (cookies, LocalStorage, etc).

By the way, you do not have to provide `desired_capabilities` when initiating the new remote driver - those are stored and inherited from the existing session you took over.

---

**Caveat** - having a SE process running can lead to some resource drainage in the system.

Whenever one is started and then not closed - like in the first piece of the code - it will stay there until you manually kill it. By this I mean - in Windows for example - you'll see a "chromedriver.exe" process, that you have to terminate manually once you are done with it. It cannot be closed by a driver that has connected to it as to a remote selenium process.
The reason - whenever you initiate a local browser instance, and then call its `quit()` method, it has 2 parts in it - the first one is to delete the session from the Selenium instance (what's done in the second code piece up there), and the other is to stop the local service (the chrome/geckodriver) - which generally works ok.

The thing is, for Remote sessions the second piece is missing - your local machine cannot control a remote process, that's the work of that remote's hub. So that 2nd part is literally a `pass` python statement - a no-op.

If you start too many selenium services on a remote hub, and don't have a control over it - that'll lead to resource drainage from that server. Cloud providers like BrowserStack take measures against this - they are closing services with no activity for the last 60s, etc, yet - this is something you don't want to do.

And as for local SE services - just don't forget to occasionally clean up the OS from orphaned selenium drivers you forgot about :)

Comment: Dear @TodorMinakov this code here didn't meet my expectations. I wanted whenever I run the python program to select the unique opened window and use selenium over that window. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: For that you need to know (have stored) both the URL to connect to - host:port, and the session id; like in the explanation above. If you have them, you'll reconnect with the steps above.

Comment: Hey, since I have already followed your instruction the `command_executor= 'http://127.0.0.1:*****'` is filled in properly so does the `sessionNumber  = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`. But actually what happens is that two new windows [2,3] are opened but none share the same data of the previously opened window [1]. So there are now three opened windows [1,2,3].

Comment: Todor, your approach worked great for me, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

OK after mixing various solutions shared on here and tweaking I have this working now as below. Script will use previously left open chrome window if present - the remote connection is perfectly able to kill the browser if needed and code functions just fine.

I would love a way to automate the getting of session_id and url for previous active session without having to write them out to a file during hte previous session for pick up...

This is my first post on here so apologies for breaking any norms

```
#Set manually - read/write from a file for automation
session_id =  "e0137cd71ab49b111f0151c756625d31"
executor_url = "http://localhost:50491"

def attach_to_session(executor_url, session_id):
    original_execute = WebDriver.execute
    def new_command_execute(self, command, params=None):
        if command == "newSession":
            # Mock the response
            return {'success': 0, 'value': None, 'sessionId': session_id}
        else:
            return original_execute(self, command, params)
    # Patch the function before creating the driver object
    WebDriver.execute = new_command_execute
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url, desired_capabilities={})
    driver.session_id = session_id
    # Replace the patched function with original function
    WebDriver.execute = original_execute
    return driver
 

remote_session = 0

#Try to connect to the last opened session - if failing open new window
try:
    driver = attach_to_session(executor_url,session_id)
    driver.current_url
    print(" Driver has an active window we have connected to it and running here now : ")
    print(" Chrome session ID ",session_id)
    print(" executor_url",executor_url)

except:
    print("No Driver window open - make a new one")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=myoptions)
    session_id = driver.session_id 
    executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
```

Answer (score 1):

for Chromium you can get a list of running processes of the browser, inspect the commandline from this process and search for "--remote-debugging-port=" extract that portnumber and use it in initialisation of the webdriver.

set the DriverOptions to

```
ChromiumOptions.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:" & remotePort
```

without any other options set initiate

```
driver As IWebDriver = New EdgeDriver(driverService, ChromiumOptions, CommandTimeout)
```

that the part in VB.net that works for me, but i think it is possbible to translate and use it in other languages too.

and use the driver as usally. you can continue at the point where the page was left open, or create a knew window and close the old one if you like a kind of fresh start, but with the previous coockies and cache.

you may want to kill old "webdriver.exe" processes, because on every reconnet it will spawn a knew one.

in this way you simulate real user behavior because normal users don't browse always in private. they came back to your site with old cookies and data in cache. so you can optimize your site to deal properly with old cached assets and find ways where the user doesn't need to force reload the site or have to clean the cache every time the site gets an update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works for me in 2023. Python code:

```
from selenium import webdrive

# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
# session_id = driver.session_id
# print(executor_url)
# print(session_id)


class SessionRemote(webdriver.Remote):
    def start_session(self, desired_capabilities, browser_profile=None):
        # Skip the NEW_SESSION command issued by the original driver
        # and set only some required attributes
        self.w3c = True


driver = SessionRemote(command_executor='your.executor.url', desired_capabilities=None)
driver.session_id = 'your-session-id'
```

I found a partial answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session.) duplicate thread and the **class definition** on another thread on stackoverflow which I cannot find right now. Uncomment the first 5 lines and comment the last 2. Then do the opposite and add your **URL** and **sessionID**.

EDIT: It only works if you run the first part in a separate terminal. You can run the second part in another terminal and reuse it as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the original poster to start this topic, and this has been very helpful discussion for me to pick up on my Python skills for a specific use-case.

I tried [Todor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52003231/3645448) method posted above and was not successful with the following setup
OS = Mac OS Ventura; Python = 3.10.4; SE = 4.12.0

However, I found this method from [Shabad](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/#launch-browser-with-custom-flags) that was helpful.

Here is my code for the above settings that worked more elegantly

Apple Script to launch a new session with a specific profile

```
do shell script "open -a /Applications/Microsoft\\ Edge.app --args --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir='~/seEdge'"
```

Python code to attach to this session

```
# Python code to attach to a specific browser session
from selenium import webdriver
import time # used to add delay in the automation script

# set option to make execution of automation scripts
edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
```

Answer (score -1):

Without getting into why do you think that leaving an open browser windows will solve the problem of being slow, you don't really need a handle to do that. Just keep running the tests without closing the session or, in other words, without calling `driver.quit()` as you have mentioned yourself. The question here though framework that comes with its own runner? Like Cucumber?

In any case, you must have some "setup" and "cleanup" code. So what you need to do is to ensure during the "cleanup" phase that the browser is back to its initial state. That means:

- Blank page is displayed
- Cookies are erased for the session

Comment: So in such case, the setup code will open the browser and navigate to this page for you, then you run all your tests and the cleanup part will close the window and the browser. This does not look like a good practice as you are adding possible issues from not having a clean session each time but can work as a workaround. Also not sure how the page will behave if you clear the cookies after teach test.

Comment: The function <code>webdriver.Chrome.get(url)</code> will wait until the page loads completely.This will take a lot of time  to load the remote page. So  I want to open and load the page once. I think the webdriver is still running background after I quit my script . So I want to find the handle for the webdriver and reconnect to the webdriver to reuse the opened page

Comment: You edited your comment after I posted a reply but have a look at it see if this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry about that .Stackoverflow sets a 5 mintues edit time.And almost every time I make it time out.

Comment: My poor English.It is my bad.

Comment: Is what I said helpful?

Comment: yeah , I know what I am thinking is wrong and the cleanup should be done everytime .Thank you very much.