# SessionNotCreatedException - selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, bdd

I have implement two scenario outlines in one feature file at cucumber, and also wrote script that new browser initiate in `@After` Junit command when my test case fail.

```
@After
public void teardownpatientregis(Scenario s) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    if(s.isFailed())
    {
        Screenshots.getscreenshot(s);
        driver.quit();
        initialize(failbrowser);
        url(failurl);
        Logintestpage.getusername(failuser);
        Logintestpage.getpassword(failpass);
        Logintestpage.loginalert();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Logintestpage.logout();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

But the new Webdriver does not initiate after close my browser. It shows SessionNotCreatedException errors. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: What have you attempted to help resolve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium/47862867#47862867)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231987/cucumber-jvs-selenium-grid-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-unable-to-cre

Answer (score 1):

The new Webdriver does not initiate after closing the browser because you are NOT closing the browser, you are issuing a quit instead.

Replace at least the first `driver.quit()` with `driver.close()`if not both of them.