# Selenium reuse brower from 2 different application

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to open 2 different tabs in the same browser session from 2  different application.
I'm using Firefox v57.0, Geckodriver v0.19.1, Selenium v3.8.0.0

The 2 apps are playing in the same time.
I'm just trying to open a new tab from app 2 X seconds after App 1 open the first tab.

**App 1:**

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.Port = 4444;

FirefoxOptions ffoptions = new FirefoxOptions();
ffoptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser.ToString(), LogLevel.All);
ffoptions.SetPreference("marionette", true);
ffoptions.LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Trace;

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, ffoptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/");
```

**App 2:**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
RemoteWebDriver driverReUse = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/"), capabilities);
driverReUse.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

**The exception:**

> "Session is already started"

Isn't it possible to do that?
Should I try to connect from App 2 to localhost with 4444?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Comment: Nope. Im using c# and not python. and Im not quiting the script. In my situation the 2 apps are opening in the same time. Im just want to open new tab in the same browser and not re-connect to old browser after I quit.

Comment: Why not just open the second tab from the first script? It's likely to work better in that the two scripts will be more in sync than if run separately.

Comment: Yes you right. It's much easier from the same script. but I need to do that from 2 apps.