# Pass a process ID to start selenium in

Tags: selenium, cucumber, autotest

How can I pass a chrome process ID to selenium to force it to start an existing browser? I tried passing arguments to capabilities but they did not help.

Thanks 
Any help is appreciated.

```
capabilities.setCapability( "pid", pid ); //$NON-NLS-1$
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Any time I've heard of somebody trying to do this in the past, the verdict was 'You can't.' I'm sure there has to be a way, but it would probably involve some pretty fancy hacks and changing the selenium source code. Alternatively, you can start a selenium browser and pause the script, do whatever you need to for setup in that instance, and then resume the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

Answering straight, **No**, you can't pass a Chrome Process ID **`[PID]`** to `Selenium` to force it to start an existing browser.

Similarly, even if you are able to extract the **`Session ID`** and other session attributes from the previous `Browsing Session` still you won't be able to pass those attributes as a `HOOK` to the **`WebDriver`**.