# How to takeover an selenium chrome driver that has not exited from previous testcase in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium

During debugging it is possible to exit test script before running cleanup code that would normally close the running chrome driver. Is it possible to take control of the existing chrome driver with a new script? If so what code is required?

What I've looked at and tried:

[Get WebDriver of already opened Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027264/get-webdriver-of-already-opened-chrome-browser)

http://testerstories.com/2015/10/using-c-with-selenium-webdriver/

[Get WebDriver of already opened Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027264/get-webdriver-of-already-opened-chrome-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Comment: Possibly this? http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-csharp/