# Selenium WebDriver attach and detach to/from a running browser

Tags: .net, selenium

I'm using selenium on **.net** I noticed that the driver inherits from RemoteWebDriver and there are a couple of hints: `CurrentWindowHandle` defined As String and `WindowHandles[]` also defined as String, but they are readonly.

I will like to attach a running browser and the after some work, detach it (not closing it).

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session) is basically asking the same you need. Take a look at the answers. There's possible to do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @CarlosParra Thanks, but most answers use java and/or python. On .net `driver` properties, but URL are readonly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)