# Editing already open website Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to mimic mouse clicks on buttons etc. on a website which is already open in a browser(e.g. Chrome). Do you guys know if I can do this with Selenium? Or do you guys know how I can do this in general?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to launch the browser with selenium by initializing the driver.  Selenium is proxying the browser so that your code can control it.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html