# can i enable/disable image loading setting in selenium with the same driver object

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

```
final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

driver.get("https://www.example.com/");
```

*This code will stop the image loading. Now I want to re-enable the Image loading again with the same driver object ??*

```
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 0);
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/present?origin=yodlee");
```

I am using this above code to changing the pref again to start loading the images again but with this code, new chrome is opening

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
```

but **I want this with the same chrome driver.**

My simple ask is to enable/disable image loading with the same driver object ?

- it will be great if some body help me on this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Comment: What you can do in this scenario is to create 2 profile then load them one by one , because you are using new ChromeDriver(capabilities) ,which would initialize the browser instance.