# How to prevent selenium to open a new chrome window on every test run?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm running selenium tests with selenium-webdriver in a react project. Every time I run the tests it opens up a new chrome window, which is extremely irritating, since I end up with a million chrome windows open. Is it possible to force selenium to use the browser window already open?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here's a simple example of the test code.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { By, Key } = webdriver

describe('Dashboard page', () => {

  it('renders correctly', async() => {
    var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
    var chromeOptions = {
      //'args': ['--headless']
    };
    chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();

    await driver.get('http://localhost:3000/dashboard')

    await driver.getTitle().then((title) => {
      expect(title).toEqual("My website | Dashboard")
    })

    await driver.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
      expect(url).toEqual("http://localhost:3000/dashboard")
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you show us your code which starts the chrome and which should close the browser. Basically you currently have coded that it opens a browser on each run, but you don't have any browser teardown.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I added a little code sample. Yes, I do open a new browser on every run. I was wondering if there is a way to tell selenium to use any currently open browser window instead of opening a new one.

Comment: If you care about reusing existing browser session (cookie, storage + maybe chrome profile) then check those links --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium cause i'm pretty sure they may be helpful in this topic (although using JavaScript).

Comment: @Wazniak Thank you! Very helpful links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using javascript bindings with Jasmine framework then you can try using below code. You can also refer jasmin docs for more details [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.2/global)

beforeEach will run only once for all tests inside a spec.js

> > Start browser session in beforeEach

afterEach will run once for all tests inside a spec.js

> > End browser session in AfterEach

```
 describe('Before Each Spec', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
  // Create new browser instance once for all spec tests
    var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
    var chromeOptions = {
      //'args': ['--headless']
    };
    chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();

  });


describe('Test Method 1', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    // TO DO Code
  });
});

describe('Test Method 2', function() {
  it('should have a something to test', function() {
    // TO DO Code
  });
});

describe('After Each Spec', function () {
  afterEach(function () {
  // Destroy browser after all tests finished
   browser.quit(); (or browser.driver.close();)

  });
```

If you are using java then you can use below annotation which runs only once for complete testng xml or once per testng class e.g. @BeforeSuite or @BeforeClass

```
@BeforeSuite
public void setUP(){
startSeleniumSession();
}

public void startSeleniumSession(){
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@Test
public void startTest2(){
driver.get("some url 1");
driver.findElement(By.id("someID")).click()
}


@Test
public void startTest2(){
// this test will run in same browser
driver.get("some url 2");
driver.findElement(By.id("someID")).click()
}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown(){
driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: I assume it's the `driver.quit()` doing the job here? I don't see how this solves the issue though, but I get your point in closing the window and at least opening only one on every test run. I want to be able to have the window open and just reuse that one.

Comment: @Majoren - I have updated the code for javascript binding. 
Idea is to keep browser creation session code in a block (beforeEach) which will execute only once. So new browser will not open,and all tests will run in same browser.

Answer (score 0):

This settings worked for me:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
```

Key thing is to set up:

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```