# How to rotate various user agents using selenium python on each request

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make 10 requests to https://www.google.com/ but with random user agents using selenium and python. I've a loop and inside that loop I'm making 10 requests with random user agents (using fake-user agent). The main problem is for every request web driver is opening a new instance of google chrome and I want to do this in one single instance but with different user agents. How can I make this possible ? 1 google chrome instance and 10 requests with 10 random user agents. Here is my code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
ua = UserAgent()
for i in range(0, 10):
    userAgent = ua.random
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent="' + str(userAgent) + '"')
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
    executable_path="C:/Python34/chromedriver")
    driver1.get('https://www.google.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First the update <sup>1</sup>

[execute_cdp_cmd()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd): With the availability of `execute_cdp_cmd(cmd, cmd_args)` command now you can easily execute [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) [commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491). Using this feature you can modify the [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) easily to prevent Selenium from getting detected.

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  # Setting user agent as Chrome/83.0.4103.97
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  # Setting user agent as Chrome/83.0.4103.53
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/headers')
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: useragent]

> Legend: <sup>1</sup> - Applicable only to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [python](/questions/tagged/python) clients.

---

### Originally *answered Nov 6 '18 at 8:00*

**No**. When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* with *ChromeOptions* to initiate a new *Chrome Browser Session* the configuration of the *ChromeDriver* remains unchanged throughout the **lifetime** of the *ChromeDriver* and remains **uneditable**. So you can't change the *user agent* when the *WebDriver* instance is executing the loop making 10 requests.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. **UserAgent**, **Session ID**, **Cookies** and other session attributes from the already initiated *Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change those attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to change the User Agent using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490495/how-to-change-the-user-agent-using-selenium-and-python/62491863#62491863)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: So I think I should use python requests library to do this task because with that I can change IP and user agent on each request and that's how we can make 10 requests using different user agents. Thank you @DebanjanB

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** It is possible now with cdp:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"User-Agent": "browser1"}})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"User-Agent": "browser2"}})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"User-Agent": "browser3"}})

driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/headers')
```

Answer (score 0):

it open 10 chrome instance because you did not`close()` it, try

```
...
...
driver1.get('https://www.whatsmyua.info/')
time.sleep(5)
driver1.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is I don't want to close the driver instance and make a new request using same instance but with different user agent. is it possible ?