# How to change the User Agent using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, user-agent

I am having an error when changing the web driver user agent in Python using selenium.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path) driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
#Error is on line above
```

Here is my error:

````
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path) driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent":"python 3.7", "platform":"Windows"}) 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path) driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent":"python 3.7", "platform":"Windows"})```
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is just **perfect**. You simply have to write the line of code to change the [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) in the next line. As an example:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  # Setting user agent as Chrome/83.0.4103.97
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  # Setting user agent as Chrome/83.0.4103.53
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/headers')
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: useragent]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to rotate various user agents using selenium python on each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161173/how-to-rotate-various-user-agents-using-selenium-python-on-each-request/53167887#53167887)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Salvatore\Desktop\Desktop\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe') `

This worked but I got this error and my browser shut down right away:

`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81`

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani That is a different error which requires a different solution. Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?

Comment: Here is my new post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492419/selenium-error-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-81

Answer (score 2):

You should use driver options:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-agent=[user-agent string]")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path', chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Is this syntax correct?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'")
```

Also, would I keep the single quotes around the actual user agent or just keep the double quotes around the whole thing and that's fine?

Comment: No need to use single quotes. Just keep the double quotes around the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps below :

1- you can use produce fake user-agent library in every request for use it

add to code  :

`from fake_useragent import UserAgent`

2- and then in terminal do this :

```
 pip install fake_useragent
```

3- use in code : for example

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=r"strin path 
chrome driver")
```

and if you want from static user-agent use this code :

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; 
WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```