# Selenium Error: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting an error when opening up chrome with Selenium, it opens up and closes the window right after opening. Here is my code:

````
import requests
import json
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Salvatore\Desktop\Desktop\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')```

This is the error:
```selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55201365/2864740

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome/60300767#60300767) help you?

Comment: Yes! How would I change the user agent tho using this. This was my solution before but without this u get the version error.

Answer (score 1):

Please check which chrome browser you are using , you should use chrome driver exe according chrome browser version ( Error seems like you are using chrome driver version of 81 but your chrome browser version no more than 81 like 83,84)

https://chromedriver.chromium.org you can download latest chrome driver version here

Comment: keep update chrome driver version based of chrome browser version

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current chrome version by going Chrome -> Options -> About Chrome and then you will know what version of the chromedriver.exe you need to download

Answer (score 0):

Your *ChromeDriver* version is required to be based on the *Chrome browser* version

- If you are using Chrome version 84, please download [ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/)
- If you are using Chrome version 83, please download [ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/)
- If you are using Chrome version 81, please download [ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.138/)