# Hotjar not launching cause of suspicious userAgent

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, undetected-chromedriver

Got this with Chrome 116 and 117 and chromedriver 116 and 117, any idea why is this happening?

"Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/116.0.5845.180 Safari/537.36", source: https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-3212388.js?sv=6 (3)

I tried using different chrome and chromedriver versions, but none of them works.

There's also a post about the same problem, but the solutions are related to modifying the chromedriver file, but in my case its just an exe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the User Agent using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490495/how-to-change-the-user-agent-using-selenium-and-python)