# How to set a custom name for the user-agent using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, user-agent

I am using selenium + webdriver and trying testing different user agents. I am adding user agent like this for Chrome on Windows for example:

```
option = Options()
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36")
```

Now when I log see login details it says Windows Chrome but when I want to rename it to something else like this:

```
option.add_argument("user-agent=test-user-agent")
```

or

```
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (test-user-agent NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36")
```

Some websites display it as `unknown` or `browser not supported`

Is there a way to "rename" user-agent or create custom one or there is only preset number of them that websites know?

Comment: Here is a massive list of user-agent strings you can use: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### User-Agent

The [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) [request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/request_header) is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/user_agent).

---

### Syntax

The common format for web browsers is as follows:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>
```

---

### This usecase

While your first code attempt to add a specific [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) would work perfect:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36
  ```

But as per your second attempt you can't rename the *User-Agent* as it violates the prescribed format/syntax.

---

However, you can always change the *User-Agent* using the [`execute_cdp_cmd(cmd, cmd_args)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd) as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  # Setting UserAgent as Chrome/83.0.4103.97
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254)
- [How to change the User Agent using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490495/how-to-change-the-user-agent-using-selenium-and-python/62491863#62491863)
- [How to rotate various user agents using selenium python on each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161173/how-to-rotate-various-user-agents-using-selenium-python-on-each-request/53167887#53167887)