# How to change the Google Chrome UserAgent using the ChromeDriver installed through webdriver_manager

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent, webdriver-manager

I recently had an issue where I couldn't change my user-agent in selenium. I got that fixed but then had a chrome driver issue where it required chrome driver version 81. I got that fixed but don't know how to implement the user-agent solution into the chrome driver-specific code.|

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Before, this is how I was changing the user agent:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Below is where my code would give me the chrome driver error. So I used the solution above for that.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User-Agent

The [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) [request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/request_header) is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/user_agent).

---

### Syntax

The common format for web browsers is as follows:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>
```

---

### webdriver_manager.chrome

[webdriver_manager.chrome](https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/) is the [python](/questions/tagged/python) module to help users to download and deploy WebDriver binaries. The classes in this module can be used to automatically search for and download the latest version (or a specific version) of a WebDriver binary and then extract it and place it by copying or symlinking it to the location where Selenium or other tools should be able to find it then.

---

### Summary

To summarize, from the above points it can be deduced that:

- [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) is implemented through the *request header* and deals with the native browser.
- [webdriver-manager](/questions/tagged/webdriver-manager) is a *Python* module to deal with downloading and installing [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) binaries.

Hence, they aren't interrelated and can be implemented combinedly as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver.get('https://duckduckgo.com/')
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  # Setting UserAgent as Chrome/83.0.4103.97
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254)
- [How to change the User Agent using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490495/how-to-change-the-user-agent-using-selenium-and-python/62491863#62491863)
- [How to rotate various user agents using selenium python on each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161173/how-to-rotate-various-user-agents-using-selenium-python-on-each-request/53167887#53167887)