# Is it possible to run Selenium with Python in my Raspberry Pi 4 and host the test page?

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi

So, I would like to automate a task with a webpage but the problem is : there is a Captcha resolution so Is it possible to host the page so I can resolve the Captcha and after the bot will automate the task?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it won't be possible to manually resolve the Captcha and let the bot automate the remaining task as [you won't be able to reconnect to the already opened *Browsing Context*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47862867/7429447).

Even if you are able to extract the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. **Session ID**, **Cookies**, **UserAgent** and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.