# Selenium log in through automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

Is selenium only for testing?

I created a script to log in to canvas, a website that my uni uses for class material
however, it seems that it only logs in on the browser generated by the driver, and I will still have to manually log in on the actual browser.

Is there a way for me to make it so that I won't have to log in on the actual browser after running my script?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH = r"C:the path \msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
driver.get("the website")
driver.maximize_window()

#sign in page
user = driver.find_element(By.ID,"username")
user.send_keys("username")
pw = driver.find_element(By.ID,"password")
pw.send_keys("password")
pw.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#authentification
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='duo_iframe']"))
remember_me = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox']")
remember_me.click()
duo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Send Me a Push "]')
duo.click()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `selenium` for this. You could use `requests` and `beautifulsoup` to achieve the same.  So it depends on what you are trying to achieve... if you are using selenium (for example, to click specific buttons) then you could use it in `headless` mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447)'s [Homepage](https://www.selenium.dev/)

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is
> entirely up to you.
>
> Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes,
> but is certainly not limited to just that.
>
> Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should) also be
> automated as well.

**No**, [you won't be able to reconnect to the already opened *Browsing Context*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47862867/7429447).

Even if you are able to extract the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. **Session ID**, **Cookies**, **UserAgent** and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the desired set of configurations.