# Is it possible to use Selenium in already opened Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

This code currently used to manipulate Chrome..

```
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
```

But this code makes to open a new chrome window.

What I want is to manipulate the chrome that's already open, is it possible?

Somebody say, Using Chrome in debug mode is answer, but I don't think that's a good choice.

I want to open chrome without any control.

Comment: Is this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session

Comment: @Prophet This is not well working Selenium 4...

Comment: This is why I not closed the question as duplicate :) Tried to know if this is still working solution. Thank you to let me know!