# Web Scrape Using an Existing Browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fetch data from a website but I need to log in first to be able to see it. I want to run my source code using an opened browser with my account already logged in on the particular website. Will that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is possible**. You need to use selenium along with chrome dev tools. The method will generate an instance of chrome, in which you have to login into the site at first sight manually. And then whenever you want you need to do some tasks the instance will open directly when called by selenium script.

**Condition** : The site must have feature to remember your login info. (Eg. Youtube, Instagram, Twitter, Facebook .etc.)  These sites remember your login even if the browser exits. Some sites may not have this functionality.

**For more clarification checkout**

**Youtube video** - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVumnHy5Tzo&ab_channel=HelloWorld

**Stack overflow post** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57001041/9807249

**Chrome devtools** - https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

I used this technique to autopost **youtube** videos.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! However, I forgot to mention that I need to log in using a chrome extension to see the website, not log in on the specific website itself. That is why I'm asking if I can run the script using the existing opened browser with my account already logged in on the particular chrome extension.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since the posts you linked dont scrape they just open the instance. How can I scrape it further?