# How can selenium automatically capture the value from an existing web browser page and use that value in the new session?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, kantu

The issue here is I'm trying to **scrape** a value which is displayed in a current webpage that I'm in and selenium has to capture that value and do certain operations accordingly. The value is dynamic and that webpage can not be reopened through selenium.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The websites can only authenticate the browsers using [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which are basically special [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) so if the browser sends the cookie the websites expects - the website "recognizes" the user and vice versa.

If you want to continue where you left off with Selenium you need to [export cookies somehow from the existing session](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg?hl=en) and add them to the browser which is driven by Selenium, there are [several API methods](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) which allow cookie manipulation, refer your Selenium client library documentation for specific instructions.