# How to keep log in credentials on Internet Explorer on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a script that opens a URL and then click on buttons on a form in Internet Explorer specifically and repeat every x minutes. The problem I'm facing is that the website requires log-in credentials and it is not quite secure to hard code credentials inside the script.

The intention so far is to have Selenium open open a new tab inside an existing instance of IE that is already logged in. This would then allow the script to perform each time without having to enter credentials each time it runs.

How would I go about either doing the above and/or performing the same outcome (having selenium work on a IE instance with the log in credentials)

Comment: You could try to use the existing instance's sessionID to interact with an existing browser session. I found a python example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session/34394556#34394556) and you could refer to it. You could also refer to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20171129014322/http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/).