# Using selenium on existing browser session

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to connect selenium to an existing session by doing the following:

```
ce = 'some url'
session_id = 'some value'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=ce,desired_capabilities={})
driver.session_id = session_id
```

I get a long error message ending with:

[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I took my code from the top answer in
[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)
However, my execution of it seems to raise an error not discussed in the original question.

EDIT: I solved my problem by saving and reusing browser cookies instead. While this does not answer the original question, it provided a solution to my particular problem. It was about not needing to log into websites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Comment: It is where i got my non working code

Comment: Then please indicate this clearly in your question.