# How to run Selenium in existing (manually created) browser session

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

### Problem

`Selenium`, by default, opens a new browser window when it runs. However, I want `Selenium` to run in an existing browser session (`Google Chrome` specifically, if that helps). I have found questions which address this request, but they end up giving solutions in `Java` or `Python`. **I would like a valid solution in `Javascript`.**

### Note

I use Node.js, and have installed `selenium-webdriver` using `npm`, so it may help when forming your answer.

Comment: Do you mean that new brower is opened, or something else?

Comment: A new window of the same browser. For example, I usually keep all my tabs in one window. When Selenium runs, a new browser window is opened, and that's where all the code is executed. I use Google Chrome and have one window open, and when Selenium runs, I have two Chrome windows open.

Comment: Hm. Selenium use webdriver, so because of that you need a new instance of it. I did not see any solution where you manually open a chrome and automated script is runing in that manually opened browser. Maybe I missunderstand you ... Also if you run part of code that say something like: var driver = new webdriver.Builder() multiple times you will get multiple webdriver windows.

Comment: What I want is the ability to run Selenium in a pre-opened Chrome window and NOT create a new window for itself.

Comment: I understand. You can not do it in your manually open browser... What do you need is to create ONLY 1 object of the webdriver and use it like Global variable (in java it would be a static global variable).

Comment: @GajJulije I asked this question because when Selenium runs and opens a new window, I access a website that requires me to be logged in (as expected). However, I am not automatically logged in, and the program that I run is very time-sensitive, so I cannot afford to spend time attempting to log in. Also, I have seen solutions to this, but in different languages. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session

Comment: @ fr0stbyte Ok. It is officialy unsupported by selenium, but you can give it a try.

Comment: @GajJulije However, I do not know how to 'translate' the Java or Python in there into Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Start chrome with debug port:

`<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1559`

And in selenium use :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: How to run Selenium in new browser session? selenium opens in existing browser and tab and it neutralize previous actions

Comment: @RF1991 create a new tab and then start test , or create tab from test and switch to it before running the test

Comment: what is the `chrome_options.add_experimental_option` or `options.add_argument` for that?

Comment: @RF1991 I am not getting your question ,  chrome_options.add_experimental_option , are to add chrome options that are not yet supported as methods of chrome_options means options which are not available like  options.headless = True , https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chromium/selenium.webdriver.chromium.options.html?highlight=chromeoptions#selenium.webdriver.chromium.options.ChromiumOptions   options.add_argument are to add arguments to chrome like : --start-fullscreen https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: I run two independent selenium code, while running the former, I run second code, and the latter runs in existing browser and it hence disrupt the running of first code, what should I do?using options.?

Comment: why can't I call driver.executeScript on sessions created using the debugging port???!