# How to get current URL from Chrome using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I want to get the URL of the currently open website in Chrome:

> from selenium import webdriver
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>
> print(driver.current_url)

However this only opens a new Chrome window with "data:," as its url.
What do I have to do to get for example "Youtube.com" when I have youtube open

Comment: You can't access Browser windows not opened via Selenium. You would need to build Chrome extension for such cases

Comment: where is the line to load youtube?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, but you actually forgot to open youtube.com URL:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/') # << Ask driver to open site of interest

print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: I think I wrote it a bit misleading. What I wanted to ask is how to get the url of an already open tab in browser. But I found out that this is impossible with selenium.

Comment: In general it is agains the spirit of Selenium, but you still could try [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)