# Restart Selenium script without loosing data

Tags: selenium

I have a classic Selenium script (in jupyter notebook) for scraping a website.I run that script and craweled hundreds of pages (clicking next-next) and finally an exception occured. Browser window is open with that session. Now I want to rerun that script from where I left in the same window maybe, before error occured. How is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code probably starts with opening new browser window and getting the url such as

```
driver=Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
```

Just comment out that lines in the next run and your code will run in the current open window where you left.