# Is it possible for selenium to find an already open webdriver session, instead of making a new tab/window? | Python | Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So let's say I've got a window open, upon starting my program, I want selenium (preferably) to be able to find/identify the specified window that's already opened up and open more tabs on that window. Is this possible at all?

If not, can I open up a selenium chrome session with one program and pick up where I left off with another program?

I'm guessing I'd somehow have to get the session ID, but that's my best guess.

Comment: Direct answer is NO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: No, officially it's not supported.
There are some workarounds for this, but it not something really simply to use.
Also, this question was already asked several times and answered there, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session/34394556)